# C++: Making a list of a multidimensional vector

Tags: c++

How do I make this work? I tried this, but no bueno. Basically, as it is, it says "for" needs a declaration, meaning there's something going on with the initialization part. I already know how to set one up. I just need to get past this part. However, if anyone can give me an alternative to making a list (or sequence container) of multidimensional arrays, that will be great, too.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MainTetris
{
    /*
        Creating a list of multidimensional vectors to represent each tetris piece.
        Don't plan on dynamically growing them in the game. It's only because
        STL list doesn't hold arrays.
    */

    list<vector< vector<int> > > pieces;

}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific than "no bueno"?

Comment: it should be `list<map<vector<vector<set<int>>>, vector<vector<set<vector<set<int>>>>>`

Comment: I edited in the follow up code to it and an explanation of what happened. @Aniket: Woah, really? That seems so convoluted. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Can we see a full example?  Do you have the right includes?  Do you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere? P.S. Aniket is f-ing with you.

Comment: I edited in what I've got so far.

Comment: Please present your *actual* code.  the psuedo-code you've presented is useless in helping us figure out your actual problem.  Read: copy-paste

Comment: If you've decided to ask a different question, make a new post.  Don't replace the text of a completely different question, thereby invalidating that question's answers.

Comment: I edited it because I heard that it's better to edit the question rather than make a new post, but I can do that, too, if I must.

Comment: You heard wrong.  This is now a completely separate question, it belongs in a completely separate post.

Comment: I've rolled back your changes so someone doesn't end up closing your other question as a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the angle brackets.

```
list<vector<vector<int> > > pieces;
```

Also you are trying to push a `vector<int>` instead of a `vector<vector<int> >`

Comment: I did so, but still the same error of "expecting declaration."

Comment: "Also you are trying to push a vector<int> instead of a vector<vector<int> >" - The single vector is to initialize seven rows. The vector starts out empty, so I need to fill it in before I start being able to use it like a normal array, i.e. vector[0][0].

Comment: As Benjamin said, that for loop needs to go in a member function. You'll still need to fix the fact that you are pushing the wrong type onto the list though.

Comment: Ah, so it seems I need to fill up both rows and columns, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a for loop in a class body.  It must be in a function.  You probably want it in your constructor.  Where did you learn to write classes that way?  Any introductory book would have covered this fairly early on.

[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I actually meant for it to be in the constructor. I was just writing on the fly. Been studying a lot of web code lately, so constructors haven't been on my mind till today. lol

Comment: @Cdore: Are you saying that the code you presented was not actually the code you tried to compile?

Comment: I'm not compiling any code as of yet. But I do admit that my brain wasn't thinking about constructors since languages such as php and javascript don't care for them. I know how to code in C++, but I've been out of it for a couple of months.

Comment: @Cdore: You're not making any sense.  If you're not compiling anything, what program is reporting that your code has an error?

Comment: Visual studio's real time error catching. It was a dumb moment for me until I realized that I was still in class initialization scope.